# Why one of the tabs in my page is not giving feedback like others?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700'); // custom font

// --------------------------------

// FAQ Template - by CodyHouse.co

// --------------------------------

:root {
  // colors
  @include defineColorHSL(--cd-color-1, 213, 7%, 33%);   // Blue Dark
  @include defineColorHSL(--cd-color-2, 73, 46%, 55%);   // Green
  @include defineColorHSL(--cd-color-3, 210, 14%, 49%);  // Blue Light
  @include defineColorHSL(--cd-color-4, 0, 0%, 100%);    // White

  // font
  --font-primary: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.cd-faq {
  box-shadow: var(--shadow-sm);

  &::before { // never visible - this is used in JavaScript to check the current MQ
    content: 'mobile';
    display: none;
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

 @include breakpoint(md) {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: none;
    display: flex;

    &::before {
      content: 'desktop';
    }
 }
}

.cd-faq__categories {
 @include breakpoint(md) {
    position: sticky; // fix element on scrolling
    align-self: flex-start;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    top: 20px;
  width: 20%;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow-sm);
    margin-top: var(--space-md);
 }

 @include breakpoint(lg) {
  width: 200px;
 }
}

.cd-faq__category {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 var(--space-lg) 0 calc(var(--space-sm)*1.4);
  color: var(--cd-color-4);
  background-color: var(--cd-color-1);
  @include fontSmooth;
  --border-color: hsl(var(--cd-color-1-h), var(--cd-color-1-s), calc(var(--cd-color-1-l)*1.1));
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border-color);

  &::before, &::after { // plus icon on the right
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: lightness(var(--cd-color-1), 1.6);
  }

  &::after {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }

  li:last-child & {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  @include breakpoint(md) {
    font-size: var(--text-xs);
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0 var(--space-md);
    transition: background .2s;

    &::before, &::after {
      display: none;
    }

    &:hover {
      background: lightness(var(--cd-color-1), 1.1);
    }
  }

  @include breakpoint(lg) {
    &::before { // decorative rectangle on the left visible for the selected item
      display: block;
      top: 0;
      right: auto;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 3px;
      background-color: var(--cd-color-2);
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity .2s;
    }
  }
}

@include breakpoint(lg) {
  .cd-faq__category-selected {
    background: lightness(var(--cd-color-1), 0.8);

    &:hover {
      background: lightness(var(--cd-color-1), 0.8);
    }

    &::before {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}

.cd-faq__items { // on mibile, faq contents slides in from the right
 position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
 height: 100%;
 width: 90%;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: var(--cd-color-4);
 padding: 0 var(--component-padding) var(--space-md);
 overflow: auto;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 transform: translateZ(0) translateX(100%);
 transition: transform .3s;

 @include breakpoint(md) {
  position: static;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: visible;
  transform: translateX(0);
  padding: 0 0 0 var(--space-sm);
  background: transparent;
 }
}

.cd-faq__items--slide-in {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

html:not(.js) .cd-faq__items {
  position: static;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.cd-faq__group {
 display: none; // hide group not selected

 @include breakpoint(md) { // all groups visible
  display: block;
    padding-top: 1px; // fix issue with collapsing margin
 }
}

html:not(.js) .cd-faq__group,
.cd-faq__group--selected {
  display: block;
}

.cd-faq__title {
  margin: var(--space-md) 0;

  h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: var(--text-sm);
    font-weight: 700;
    color: lightness(var(--color-contrast-low), 0.9);
  }

  @include breakpoint(md) {
    margin-bottom: var(--space-sm);
    
    h2 {
      font-size: var(--text-xs);
    }
  }
}

.cd-faq__item {
  @include breakpoint(md) {
    background: var(--cd-color-4);
    margin-bottom: var(--space-xxxs); 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(#000, .08);
    transition: box-shadow .2s;

    &:hover {
      --box-shadow: hsla(var(--cd-color-3-h), var(--cd-color-3-s), var(--cd-color-3-l), 0.3);
      box-shadow: 0 1px 10px var(--box-shadow);
    }

    &:last-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
  }
}

.cd-faq__trigger {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: var(--space-md) 0 var(--space-xs);
  color: var(--cd-color-2);

  @include breakpoint(md) {
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0;
    padding: var(--space-sm) var(--space-lg) var(--space-sm) var(--space-sm);

    span {
      font-size: var(--text-md);
    }

    &::before, &::after { // arrow icon on the right
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: 24px;
      top: 50%;
      height: 2px;
      width: 13px;
      background: lightness(var(--cd-color-2), 1.3);
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      transition: transform .2s;
    }

    &::before {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      right: 32px;
    }

    &::after {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }

    .cd-faq__item-visible &::before {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }

    .cd-faq__item-visible &::after {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
  }
}

.cd-faq__content {
  .text-component {
    font-size: 0.95em;
  }
  
  p {
    color: var(--cd-color-3);
  }

  @include breakpoint(md) {
    display: none;
    padding: 0 var(--space-sm);
    overflow: hidden;
    
    .text-component {
      font-size: 0.75em;
      padding-bottom: var(--space-md);
    }
  }
}

.cd-faq__content--visible {
  display: block;
}

html:not(.js) .cd-faq__content {
  @include breakpoint(md) {
    display: block; // always display faq content
  }
}

.cd-faq__close-panel { // on small device -> x icon to close faqs panel
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  top: 5px;
  right: -40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  // Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit
  transform: translateZ(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: right .3s;

  &::before, &::after { // close icon in CSS
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 3px;
    width: 18px;
    background: var(--cd-color-3);
  }

  &::before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  &::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }

  @include breakpoint(md) {
    display: none;
  }
}

.cd-faq__close-panel--move-left {
  right: var(--component-padding);
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.cd-faq__overlay { // overlay visible on small devices when the right panel slides in
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: alpha(var(--cd-color-1), 0.8);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s, visibility .3s;

  @include breakpoint(md) {
    display: none;
  }
}

.cd-faq__overlay--is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

// demo style
body {
  background-color: var(--color-contrast-lower);
}

.cd-header {
  --header-height: 180px;
  height: var(--header-height);
  background-color: var(--cd-color-2);

  h1 {
    font-size: var(--text-xl);
    font-weight: 300;
    color: var(--cd-color-4);
    @include fontSmooth;
  }

  @include breakpoint(lg) {
    --header-height: 240px;
  }
}

.cd-article-link {
  color: lightness(var(--cd-color-2), 0.5);
  font-size: var(--text-sm);
}
```

I'm using a template to create a FAQ page. The tabs will show feedback once it has been selected. But after I removed one of it, the last tab is not working properly. I could not find out what is the problem. Not sure whether it is an error in html or css.[Im clicking on the contact us tab but it is not showing any feedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4JLj.png) The thing is it is functioning properly, but i just want it to show some feedback when it has been clicked like in the picture. [This is the real template and i just removed the last tab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HULe.png)

This is the code for the last tab of the original template.

```
<ul id="delivery" class="cd-faq__group">
    <li class="cd-faq__title"><h2>Delivery</h2></li>
    <li class="cd-faq__item">
        <a class="cd-faq__trigger" href="#0"><span>What should I do if my
            order hasn't been delivered yet?</span></a>
        <div class="cd-faq__content">
            <div class="text-component">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                    Impedit quidem delectus rerum eligendi mollitia, repudiandae 
                    quae beatae. Et repellat quam atque corrupti iusto architecto impedit 
                    explicabo repudiandae qui similique aut iure ipsum quis inventore nulla 
                    error aliquid alias quia dolorem dolore, odio excepturi 
                    veniam odit veritatis.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- cd-faq__content -->
    </li>
```

This is the code after I removed the last tab

```
<ul id="privacy" class="cd-faq__group">
    <li class="cd-faq__title"><h2>Contact Us</h2></li>
    <li class="cd-faq__item">
        <a class="cd-faq__trigger" href="#0"><span>I am still unsure or need
            more information. Can I email Headstart and get a response 
            instantly?</span></a>
        <div class="cd-faq__content">
            <div class="text-component">
                <p>
                    Yes. You can email to hello@headstart.my. We will get back 
                    to you as soon as possible. 
            </div>
        </div> <!-- cd-faq__content -->
    </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: The problem is most likely on css/javascript definitions. The HTML itself won't contain any decisive information to debug it, besides the hypothesis that the problem might be caused because you started using the id `privacy` instead of `delivery`. But again, to be sure, we'd have to check css.

Comment: I formatted the html and can see that the `<p>` tag in the second example is not closed.

Comment: @Izbernardo I have already added the css.

Comment: @wazz I have tried that too, but it still doesn't work.